# Maatwebsite not exporting in Laravel php

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I have a problem in which I cannot trace the error/problem when trying to export and download my `Users` table in excel using `Maatwebsite`  I've followed step by step with this reference here [link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/laravel-import-export-excel-file/) but it didn't export the data through excel,

Is there any wrong with my implementation? Is somebody have an idea what's the problem? I appreciate any comments

[image]

**index.blade.ph**

```
<li class="navi-item">
     <a href="#" class="navi-link">
           <span class="navi-icon">
               <i class="la la-file-excel-o"></i>
           </span>
           <span class="navi-text" @click="exportData()">Excel</span>
     </a>
</li>
```

**Index.js**

```
methods: {
    init() {
       var vm = this;
       var t;
       $(document).ready(function() {
          vm.$toaster.init();
          vm.setConfig();
          });
        },
    exportData(){
       let vm = this;
       $.ajax({
           url: vm.$route('staff.ajax.emvvalidationdetails.exportemv'),
           type: 'GET',
           success: function (response) {
             if (response) {        
                        // console.log("Test");                  

                    }
                },

            });

        },
```

**Staff ajax**

```
 Route::group(['prefix' => 'emvvalidationdetails', 'namespace' => 'Emvvalidationdetails'], function () {
    Route::get('exportemv', 'EmvvalidationdetailsController@exportemv')->name('staff.ajax.emvvalidationdetails.exportemv');
});
```

**EmvvalidationdetailsController**

```
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
  use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
  use App\Imports\ImportUser;
  use App\Exports\ExportUser;
  use App\Models\User;

  public function exportemv(Request $request){
    return Excel::download(new ExportUser, 'users.xlsx');
}
```

**ExportUser.php** in app/Exports

```
<?php

  namespace App\Exports;
  use App\Models\User;
  use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;

  class ExportUser implements FromCollection
  {
   /**
   * @return \Illuminate\Support\Collection
   */
   public function collection()
  {
    return User::select('username','email','password')->get();
  }
 }
```

Comment: Why are you using ajax instead of just using link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can download it this way

**`<a href="{{route('...')}}" target="_blank">Download</a>`**

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the response's `Content-Type` is not being set correctly. Maybe it gets messed up by some package or other part of your codes. See the doc [here](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/export-formats.html) to manually set the `Content-Type`.